# How to wire a light fitting with two black wires and one white wire?

Tags: light-fixture

I bought a light fixture from a second hand shop. It has two black wires and one white wire. How should I wire it to the mains (with ground, live, neutral)?

It came with a two wire junction box with the two black wires connected to one pin, and the white wire connected to the other pin.

Is there any logic in using the two junction box? Or should I buy a 3 junction box, and if so how do I know which of the wires should connect to ground, neutral and live?

Comment: Can you post some pictures of the light fixture itself and of how the wires come out of it?

Comment: Quite a few lights don't use a ground wire, so it is usually just connected to the junction box.  If both blacks from light are connected together, then usually just black to black, and white to white, to connect the light.

Comment: could be a 3 way light fitting, yeah pleas show photos.